# Self-complementary graph and cut-vertices

Tags: graph-theory

Statement: A self-complementary graph has a cut-vertex if and only if it has a
vertex of degree 1.

It is true that if $v$ is a cut-vertex, then at least there are two components that when one calculates $\bar{G}$, one get a $\bar{K}_{H,K}$ graph. But since $G=\bar{G}$, then G is also at least bipartite $K_{H,K}$. [Here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wikipedia:Reference_desk/Archives/Mathematics/2011_April_13) it says that H or K must be a single vertex, but I think that's not correct, since $P_4$ is bipartite and each partition has 2 vertices (but $P_4$ is not $K_{2,2}$!). This, however, could be a bad example because there are 2 vertices of degree 1. How do you prove then the statement?

Incidentally, if one says that $G$ has to be $K_{1,K}$, then one does not only have one vertex with degree 1, but $k$ vertices fulfills this!

Comment: The answer you provided is correct, "has a vertex" means "has at least one vertex".

Comment: I found [here](http://onlinelibrary.wiley.com/doi/10.1002/jgt.3190050108/abstract) that: "A self-complementary graph does not have exactly one endpoint." I don't know what you think, but maybe the statement has to be rephrased to say __has $s$ ($s>1$) vertices of degree one__.

Comment: Incidentally, I don't think that $K_{1,K}$ (or the star graph) is self-complementary.

Comment: Star graph can never be self-complementary. Your rephrased version is correct, but usually mathematicians also see the original statement as true.